# Is my dwarf orange tree too young to bear fruit?

Tags: fruit-trees, citrus

I planted a dwarf orange this winter.  It came from the nursery with oranges already on it.  They are still green, and one split through the skin so I cut it off.  Should I leave the rest on?  Or would it be better to let the tree get established and take all the green fruit off?

Answer (score 5):

A lot depends on the local environment where the tree is. At the grower's, conditions were optimized for growth and fruit production.  If your tree has good light, humidity over 30 or 40 percent and a regular watering and fertilizing schedule with a citrus fertilizer that provides chelated minor nutrients, then leave the fruit on.

A tree in less than optimum conditions can still flower and set fruit but a good practice would be to do some thinning at fruit set so it can grow a few fruits well.

Watch out for spider mites on the underside of the leaves if it is dry (humidity less than 30 percent on a regular basis). Soap and water on a dishcloth wiped on the underside of the leaves will control them.