# What should I do to prevent citrus trees from "burned" branches?

Tags: indoors, citrus, dead-branch

I have 6 citrus trees which I treat same way but 2 of them have this problem and about 3 months ago 1 smaller has not survived.
As a fertilizer I use agro nitrogen - phosphorus - potassium: 5 - 6 – 6 and they are grown indoor.

If you have additional questions, pleas ask me.

[image]

Comment: this link to many question and answers about nutrient deficiency in citrus http://gardening.stackexchange.com/search?q=citrus+deficiency  . Your plants seem to have Iron/Manganese deficiency brought on by alkaline soil ph or heavy flower/fruit production.

Comment: So what are possible solutions?

Comment: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/a/20358/499

Comment: Thanks for the articles. I will find better sunny place for it. About soil, what should I measure (what numbers I should get - PH...), so I could see where is exact problem. Or if you know from picture what additives it needs, feel free to write it.